# SQL SELECT distinct query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table that consist of `no(auto increment)`, `user(varchar)`, `timein (timestamp)`, `timeout (timestamp)`.

I want to get multiple user timein and timeout, and i have some problem getting it.

The closest i can get is from :

```
SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE no IN (SELECT MIN(no) FROM userdata GROUP BY user) 
UNION  
SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE no IN (SELECT MAX(no) FROM userdata GROUP BY user)
```

The output i get is:

```
[{"no":"1","user":"Alan","timein":"2017-01-12 12:31:19","timeout":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"no":"3","user":"Alan","timein":"2017-01-12 12:34:00","timeout":"2017-01-12 12:34:00"}]
```

Is there any way that i can get distinct user(so the output does not repeat) and display MIN(timein) and MAX(timeout) in a single line SQL?

***Desired output: {"user":"Alan","timein":"12:31:19","timeout":"12:34:00"}***

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------|------------|
|         no          |     user         |   timein   |   timeout  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|------------|
|          1          |        Alan      |12:31:19    | 12:31:19   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|------------|
|          2          |        Bill      |12:33:00    | 12:33:00   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|----------- |
|          3          |        Alan      |12:34:00    | 12:34:00   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|----------- |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user, MIN(timein), MAX(timeout)
FROM userdata
GROUP BY user
```

Try that, use a group by statement, maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY user) AS no,user, MIN(timein), MAX(timeout)
FROM USER_TABLE GROUP BY user
```